# Reverse DNS with authentication

Tags: domain-name-system, authentication, reverse-dns

I plan to setup a reverse dns server (bind) on a machine that is available on the public web. To prevent unwanted lookups I'd like to use some kind of authentication mechanism.

I haven't found anything useful so far, therefore a hint into the right direction would be highly appreciated.

Comment: tsig or Kerberos?

Comment: What is a "reverse" DNS server? Why should it be not public? What are really your goals here?

Comment: My ISP started censoring the internet. therefore i need a new DNS Server which i can trust, why not using a reverse resolver. I don't want that anybody can use this free dns server, because it can result in a legal issue with the authorities. Authentication is needed to control this. Finally I will provide a DNS to friends and family

Comment: In your situation, an own VPN server could be a better alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DNS message format ([RFC 1035 section 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035#section-4)) doesn't have any space or method for authentication.

Instead of authentication, BIND has [Access Control Lists (ACL)](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/acl.html). With ACLs you can control what IPs and subnets can perform what operations: `allow-query`, `allow-recursion`,
`allow-transfer` etc.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I think I'll use a proxy with authentication, only the proxy is allowed by IP allow to do reverse queries.